# SQL - Return Last Update Date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return the **LastUpdateDate** based on a **ParentID**. This date can come from any of it's child tables. Let's say there are two child tables. Child one has a one to one relationship with the Parent and child two has a many to many relationship. See test tables below. Any help would be appreciated.

Parent Table

```
ParentID    Name      LastUpdateDate
1        Parent John     2014-06-26
2        Parent Mark     2004-07-27
3        Parent Bob      2009-04-07
4        Parent Jo       2014-09-26
```

ChildOne Table (1-1 Relationship)

```
ChildOneID  ParentID    Name            LastUpdateDate
10             1    FirstChild Tom        2011-03-12
20             2    FirstChild David      2014-08-11
30             3    FirstChild Sally      2009-04-06
40             4    FirstChild Jane       2014-11-26
```

ChildTwo Table (many - many Relationship)

```
ChildTwoID  ParentID    Name            LastUpdateDate
100             1   SecondChild Phil       2014-03-12
200             2   SecondChild Smith      2012-08-10
300             3   SecondChild Paul       1999-04-06
400             4   SecondChild Ed         2010-11-26
500             2   SecondChild Donna      2010-08-10
600             4   SecondChild Melissa    2008-10-16
```

Comment: There's something really strange in your database design. What's the purpose of ChildTwo? And children in ChildOne table have only one parent - one child relationship?

Comment: Probably real parent and children wasn't the best example. Let's just say that I'm trying to find the LastUpdateDate on any of the three tables no matter what ParentID I lookup. For example it I search on ParentID 2, my answer should be 2014-08-11. That result came from the second table above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT parent.parentId, MAX(updateTimes.LastUpdateDate) as LastUpdate
FROM parent
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT parentID, LastUpdateDate
        FROM childTable1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT parentID, LastUpdateDate
        FROM childTable2
        -- you may add more tables
        -- you may also filter or group the subqueries
    ) as updateTimes
        ON parent.parentID = updateTimes.parentID
GROUP BY parent.parentId
```

Comment: I need it to include the parent table in the search as well.